# How to rename file in Java [ Ubuntu platform ]?

Tags: java, ubuntu, file-rename

I want to rename a file in Java. My working platform is Ubuntu. The `renameFile()` didn't work for me. Is there any other ways to rename a file ?

ADDED :

```
File file = new File( "/home/test/filename.txt" );

if ( file.renameTo( new File( "/home/test/modified.txt" ) ) ) {
    System.out.println( "Rename succesful" );
} else {
    System.out.println( "Rename failed" );
}
```

Comment: What have you tried and what are the errors you get? Do other operations work on the file? Do you have access rights to the file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `File.renameTo(newFileName)`

If this doesn't work, you need to work out why as this method isn't very helpful. e.g. you can't rename a files which isn't there or you don't have permissions to the directories.

Comment: [API of renameTo()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#renameTo(java.io.File))

Comment: Yeah, Sounds like it's access privilege issue. I tried renaming the file in a different location. It worked. Just wondering though, the instance variable 'file' is holding the previous file name. i.e. file.getName() is giving me the old name "filename.txt".

Comment: @ManojShrestha The File object is immutable so it doesn't change.  It is just a reference to a path which may or may not exist.